# using AjaxSubmitButton in yii2 show preloder and submit form

Tags: php, yii2

when click on submit button all form validation show require only related service gives nothing see image below--

[image]

and this is code. one select option "RELETED SERVICE" validation is not working thats why form submit is not working any suggestions. Yii2 AjaxSubmitButton and using preloader and then submit form.

```
    <?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\helpers\BaseHtml;
    use yii\widgets\DetailView;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use app\models\Countries;
    use app\models\Ticket;
?>

<div class="ibox-title"><h5><?=Yii::t('app', 'SUPPORT TICKETS') ?> <small><?=Yii::t('app', 'If you can\'t find a solution to your problems in our knowledgebase, you can submit a ticket by selecting the appropriate department below.') ?></small></h5></div>


<div class="ibox-content">   

    <div id="paypal_loader">

    </div>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
            ['action' =>'',
            'options' => ['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'frm-introduction','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'],
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'template' => "{label}<div class=\"col-md-4\">{input}\n{error}</div>",
                'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'],
            ],
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'enableClientValidation' => true,'validateOnSubmit'=>true]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'deptid')->dropDownList(Ticket::getSupportDepartment(),['prompt'=>'Select...']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'subject'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'priority')->dropDownList(Ticket::getPriority(),['prompt'=>'Select...']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'serviceid')->dropDownList(Ticket::getRelatedServices(),['prompt'=>'Select...']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textArea(['rows'=>'9','cols'=>'6']); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'attachments[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']); ?>

  <!--  <?php if(!$missing){ ?> -->
              <div class="form-group m-t-20">
          <div class="pull-right">

          <input type="hidden" name="buttonclick" id="buttonclick" value="0">
          <?php app\vendor\demogorgorn\yii2ajax\AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                      'label' => Yii::t('app','Submit Ticket'),
                      'id'=>'card-button',
                      'ajaxOptions' => [
                          'type'=>'POST',                                                
                          'url'=>new \yii\web\JsExpression('$(this).closest("form")[0].action'),
                          'beforeSend'=> new \yii\web\JsExpression('function() {

                                      $("#paypal_loader").html("<div class=\"sk-spinner sk-spinner-three-bounce\"><div class=\"sk-bounce1\"></div><div class=\"sk-bounce2\"></div><div class=\"sk-bounce3\"></div></div>");


                                  }'),
                          'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(response){   

                                  $("#paypal_loader").html("");
                                        console.log(response);    
                                       if(jQuery.type(response)!="object"){
                                          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                       } 
                                      console.log(obj);                                             

                                  if(jQuery.type(response)=="object"){
                                      $("#buttonclick").val(0);
                                      $("#card-button").removeAttr("disabled");
                                      //$("#existingcard-btn").removeAttr("disabled");


                                  }else if(obj[0].form){
                                    $("#form3d").html(obj[0].form);


                                  }else{
                                      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                      console.log(obj);




                                  }
                          }'),
                      ],
                      'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit','name'=>'card-button','value'=>'send','onclick'=>'$("#buttonclick").val(1);'],
                      ]);
                  app\vendor\demogorgorn\yii2ajax\AjaxSubmitButton::end();
                  ?>

                                     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/ticket/index" data-toggle="block" data-reset="#w6"  data-target="dt-aboutme">Cancel</a>

                                  <!-- <?php } ?> -->

                              </div></div>

                  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div id="form3d"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#frm-introduction").on("submit", function(){

       });

</script>
```

this is ajaxsubmitbutton- when use loader then submit will not work and when submit use loader process will not work. what should i do any suggesstion. how AjaxSubmitButton is work with loder process and submit form.

```
<?php app\vendor\demogorgorn\yii2ajax\AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                'label' => Yii::t('app','Submit Ticket'),
                'id'=>'card-button',
                'ajaxOptions' => [
                    'type'=>'POST',                                                
                    'url'=>new \yii\web\JsExpression('$(this).closest("form")[0].action'),
                    'beforeSend'=> new \yii\web\JsExpression('function() {

                                $("#paypal_loader").html("<div class=\"sk-spinner sk-spinner-three-bounce\"><div class=\"sk-bounce1\"></div><div class=\"sk-bounce2\"></div><div class=\"sk-bounce3\"></div></div>");


                            }'),
                    'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(response){   

                            $("#paypal_loader").html("");
                                  console.log(response);    
                                 if(jQuery.type(response)!="object"){
                                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                 } 
                                console.log(obj);                                             

                    }'),
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit','name'=>'card-button','value'=>'send','onclick'=>'test(1)'],
                ]);
            app\vendor\demogorgorn\yii2ajax\AjaxSubmitButton::end();
            ?>

                                 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/ticket/index" data-toggle="block" data-reset="#w6"  data-target="dt-aboutme">Cancel</a>

                              <!-- <?php } ?> -->

                          </div></div>

              <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
              </div>
              <div id="form3d"></div>
```

Comment: Check browser console for errors, then check whether it send ajax query to validate date?

Comment: please add your `function rules` of your model class to see your validacion

Comment: how AjaxSubmitButton is work with loder process and submit form.